# Create video with filmstrip effect with Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere

I'm a wedding photographer and I'm trying to create a slideshow for my customer. She want a moving filmstrip effect where her image will fill in a 35mm film, and it keeps scrolling. It looks similar to this.

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IeRD6mP5YxA/maxresdefault.jpg

I don't have any clues about how to create this. I have Adobe Premiere but kind of newbie to it. Any clues will be appreciated.

P/s: sorry, my English is bad.

Comment: http://www.audiomicro.com/royalty-free-music-blog/2013/01/adobe-premiere-pro-filmstrip-animation-and-more/

Comment: Tks. I got a tutorial from Premiere forum, similar to this one. I need to add "film" border to all images I want to appear in filmstrip animation.

Comment: Buy a ready-made template and use After Effects (you're never going to get a clean pro look with Premiere). Include the price of the template to your fee (you'll be able to use the template again for future projects).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are trying to do is create a mask with the film strip.

If you are seeing (lets say) 3 frames, then you would duplicate your original image 3 times, and offset each one by one frame. Feel free to cheat more than a frame to get the right look.

Then scale and rotate the images to fit under the film strip.

That is how I would do it.

Other things you might consider doing.

Reducing the frame rate to around 12 frames a second, to make it look more like the old silent movies.
Add dust and scratches effect
Add light leaks effects as well
And add a jitter effect (many ways to do that)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have suggested that you already have Premiere, I must point out that After Effects is a popular choice for such applications. Wedding videographers often make use of templates created by others to illustrate their videos.

For example, you can make use of this free After Effects template to showcase of your photos:
[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2MPl3QsH2w)

Through using a template you could simply add your photos in and render the final result, without having to draw or automate anything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this After Effects Free template to create the effect you mentioned.

https://www.pond5.com/after-effect/1038234/film-strip.html

Just drop your footage/pictures in the template and your project will be complete in no time.

See this video to know how it will look:

Or you can go to videohive.net and chose from hundreds of AE templates :
https://videohive.net/search/filmstrip%20slideshow?as=1&referrer=homepage&type=l&utf8=%E2%9C%93

for example :
https://s3.envato.com/h264-video-previews/14110496-223e-49f8-85cb-907f086a5646/17175254.mp4

If your requirement of filmstrip effect is not so strict I can tell you one free alternative.. Checkout the link as given below from Rocketstock.com, this templates resembles very close to what you are looking but it is not exactly the filmstrip slideshow effect as you want. But it looks very elegant and your client may like it as well. The good thing about it is that it is free and wouldn't cost you a dime.

https://www.rocketstock.com/free-after-effects-templates/fast-slides-free-slideshow-template/

This is how it will look: